# Не запускается приложение

Tags: android

При приложения на эмуляторе приложение работает корректно, когда достаю apk-debag с папки проекта и устанавливаю на реальном устройстве, приложение крашится. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А зачем нужно вытаскивать отладочный билд и запускать его на устройстве?

Comment: Хочу его переслать для тестирования

Comment: Смотрите стектрейс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, нужно подписать приложение, тогда даже сборка debug должна запускаться. В IDEA это находится тут:
Build -> Generate Signed APK.